# How to get the average of all the dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, input

I can't find the average of all the inputs. My code only reads the input that i stated in html, but doesn't read the other dynamic ones.

Heres my code:

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
        // adds a new row
     $(".addCF").click(function(){
      $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add">Add </a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
        });
        // deletes the row
        $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
        $("#customFields").on('click','.add',function(){
          $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add">Add </a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
        });
        $("#click").click(function(){
            var isbn = document.getElementById('customFieldName').value;
            alert(isbn / $("input").length)
            $("#averageGrade").text("Average Grade: " + isbn)
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form-table" id="customFields">
     <tr valign="top">
      <th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th>
      <td>
       <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp;
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id = "click" class = "btn btn-primary" >Hi</button>
    <p id = "averageGrade">Average Grade:</p>
```

Please help! 
Thanks!

Comment: You are having more than one element with the same id. You should use a class instead.

Comment: It's a selector issue. You're going by ID, which means that your functions only look for the immediate instance of that ID and then stops looking. What you need is a class, loop through the values and calculate your average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `element.id` must be unique - please change `customFieldName` to a class, and then iterate over the inputs and calculate the average.  Also, you can reuse the same class for all "add" buttons and save that string in a variable so you don't have to [paste it multiple times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

```js
let inputTemplate = '<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label>Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="text" class="customFieldName code" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add </a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>';

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // adds a new row
  $("#customFields").on('click', '.addCF', function() {
    $("#customFields").append(inputTemplate);
  });

  // deletes the row
  $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

  $("#click").click(function() {

    let fields = $('.customFieldName'),
        total = 0;
        
    for (let field of fields)
      total += Number(field.value);
      
    let average = total / fields.length;
    $("#averageGrade").text("Average Grade: " + average);
    
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form-table" id="customFields">
  <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row"><label>Custom Field</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="customFieldName code" name="customFieldName[]" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="click" class="btn btn-primary">Hi</button>
<p id="averageGrade">Average Grade:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a way to select all the fields. Since `id` must (should) be unique, you could use the name or the class `.code` and remove `id="customFieldName"`.

Then, `getElementById`, as its name suggests, returns one element. You need to select them all! If you're using class names, you can use `getElementsByClassName`, or `querySelectorAll`, or, since you're already using jQuery, just `$(".code")`, along with a loop to read each input's value (it you use jQuery, you can also use `each()`).

```
var sum=0,count=0,average;
$(".code").each(function() {
    var value=parseInt($(this).val());
    //You may want to validate the field
    if(!isNaN(value)) sum+=value;
    count++;
});
average=sum/count;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As many has pointed out (including myself in the comment section), you are going about using the wrong selector. `id` is a unique selector, meaning that the script will look at the first instance of the `id` and then stop immediately after.

What you need to do is use a selector that goes through every occurance of its instance. This is why `class` selectors exist. That will be the first fix in your code.

How I would go about calculating the average, personally, would be to make an array and `push();` the values of the grades into the array. We will also need to do a `parseInt()` to make sure that our values are in fact handled as `numbers`. Otherwise, they'll be interpreted as `strings`.

You will then need to loop through the array, sum the values and divide by the length of the array.

**HTML Example:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table form-table" id="customFields">
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label>Custom Field</label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" class="customFieldName" placeholder="Input Number" /> &nbsp;
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="calcAvrgBtn" class="btn-primary">Calculate average grade</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="averageCalc"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Example:**

```
$('.addCF').on("click", function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label>Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="number" class="customFieldName" placeholder="Input Number" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
});

$(document).on("click", "a.remCF" , function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$('#calcAvrgBtn').on("click", function() {
    let gradeArr = [];

    $('.customFieldName').each(function() {
        gradeArr.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
    });

    let total = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < gradeArr.length; i++) {
        total += gradeArr[i];
    }

    let avg = total / gradeArr.length;

    $('#averageCalc').text("The average grade is: "+avg);
});
```

Codepen example can be found [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/dyGXrPB).

**Snippet Example:**

```js
$('.addCF').on("click", function() {
 $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label>Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="number" class="customFieldName" placeholder="Input Number" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
});

$(document).on("click", "a.remCF" , function() {
 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$('#calcAvrgBtn').on("click", function() {
 let gradeArr = [];
 
 $('.customFieldName').each(function() {
  gradeArr.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
 });

 let total = 0;
 
 for(var i = 0; i < gradeArr.length; i++) {
  total += gradeArr[i];
 }
 
 let avg = total / gradeArr.length;
 
 $('#averageCalc').text("The average grade is: "+avg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <table class="table form-table" id="customFields">
   <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row"><label>Custom Field</label></th>
    <td>
     <input type="number" class="customFieldName" placeholder="Input Number" /> &nbsp;
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <button id="calcAvrgBtn" class="btn-primary">Calculate average grade</button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <p id="averageCalc"></p>
 </div>
</div>
```